# filtering a parameter in a where clause using an if/case statement

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, switch-statement

I have two queries as such

```
select *
from table 1
where id=145
```

query 2

```
select *
from table 1
where code=452 and typeCode <> 3
```

How do i filter a where condition based on the parameter value,for example i have the following parameter that can be a "History" or "latest" as such

```
Declare @Type nvarchar(10)
set @Type='History'
```

so now i want to say in my where clause if type = history than do the first query if its equal to latest than do the second query

```
select *
from table 1
where if @Type='History'
then 
id=145
else if @type='latest'
then
code=452 and typeCode <> 3
```

or how to use a case with the above

```
where case @type='History'
then
id=145
when @type='Latest'
then
code=452 and typeCode <> 3
```

i can not get the syntax correct,how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `OR` operator

```
select *
from table 1
where (
       @Type='History'
       AND id=145 
      )
OR 
      (
       @type='latest'
       AND code=452 
       and typeCode <> 3
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case-when in the where clause like this:

```sql
DECLARE @type varchar (15)
SET @type = 'History'
--SET @type = 'Latest'


SELECT TOP (1000) *     
        FROM [AdventureWorksDW].[dbo].[FactResellerSales]
WHERE ProductKey = (CASE WHEN @type = 'History' THEN 349
                         WHEN @type = 'Latest' THEN 350
                         END)
        AND CurrencyKey = (CASE WHEN @type = 'History' THEN 100
                                WHEN @type = 'Latest' THEN CurrencyKey
                                END)
```

With your code:

```sql
DECLARE @type varchar (15)
SET @type = 'History'
--SET @type = 'Latest'


SELECT *     
        FROM table1
WHERE id = (CASE WHEN @type = 'History' THEN 145
                 WHEN @type = 'Latest' THEN id
                 END)
        AND typeCode <> (CASE WHEN @type = 'Latest' THEN 3 
                              ELSE '' END)
        AND code = (CASE WHEN @type = 'History' THEN code
                         WHEN @type = 'Latest' THEN 452
                         END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example has hardcoded values in them.  If you wanted each of those things to be optional you can default your parameters to null and do your where statement like this

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procMyProcedure
   @ID int = NULL,
   @Code int = NULL,
   @NotTypeCode int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM tblMyTable
   WHERE (@ID IS NULL OR id = @ID) AND
      (@Code IS NULL OR code = @Code) AND
      (@NotTypeCode IS NULL OR typeCode <> @NotTypeCode)
END
```

You can then in code figure out which of those parameters you want to pass based on your "history" or "latest".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as

```
where id = ( case when @type = 'History' then 145 else id end )
and code = ( case when @type = 'Latest'  then 452 else code end )
and typecode = ( case when @type = 'Latest' and typeCode = 3 then -1 
                 else typeCode 
                 end 
               )
```